# How to enter questionText from objects inside array inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, use-state

I have tried to enter questionText by inputFields.questions.questionText, but it is not working

```js
const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    {
      sectionName: "",
      sectionDesc: "",
      questions: [{ questionType: "", questionText: "" }],
    },
  ]);

<input value={inputFields.questions.questionText} />
```

Comment: `inputFields` and `questions` are arrays not an `object`. You have to use `array indexing` to get value `inputFields[0].questions[0]. questionText`

Comment: When I did above, input value is not writable, in other words, you cannot write in the input

Answer (score 1):

**`1)`**
`questions` and `inputFields` are arrays not an object so you should use `index` to access its value as:

```
value={inputFields[0].questions[0].questionText}
```

**`2)`** If you want to change input value on input of `value` then you have to use `onChange` here as:

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-gauss-jdtx2n?file=/src/App.js)

```
function onChangeInput(e) {
    setInputFields((currValue) => {
        const clone = [...currValue];
        clone[0].questions[0].questionText = e.target.value;
        return clone;
    });
}
```